# Morelike this Query eats up memory

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 nodes 2 masters with data and 1 is master=false and data=false used for facets,aggregation.
All nodes are having 30gb ram with 16gb allocated to elastic search and remaining OS
I have some 600 indices with 5 shards each storing content of documents with vector=true.
Now when I execute a simple more like this query,first 2 nodes starts eating up memory resulting into out of memory exception.Am i missing any settings? or is this a bug?

This is the error log

```
[2015-06-12 04:19:35,729][DEBUG][action.search.type ] [Master1] [113] Failed     to execute fetch phase
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Java heap space
at org.elasticsearch.ExceptionsHelper.convertToRuntime(ExceptionsHelper.java:44)
at     org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeFetchPhase(SearchService.java:513)
at          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$17.call(SearchServi    ceTransportAction.java:452)
at   org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$17.call(SearchServi   ceTransportAction.java:449)
at    org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServic    eTransportAction.java:559)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)
at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.contentsAsString(TextBuffe    r.java:349)
at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:281)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.text(JsonXContentParser.java:86)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.readValue(AbstractXContentParser.java:293)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.readMap(AbstractXContentParser.java:275)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.readMap(AbstractXContentParser.java:254)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.map(AbstractXContentParser.java:208)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.mapAndClose(AbstractXContentParser.java:219)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.convertToMap(XContentHelper.java:125)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.convertToMap(XContentHelper.java:79)
at org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.SourceLookup.sourceAsMapAndType(SourceLookup.java:87)
at org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.SourceLookup.loadSourceIfNeeded(SourceLookup.java:63)
at org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.SourceLookup.extractRawValues(SourceLookup.java:145)
at org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.createSearchHit(FetchPhase.java:245)
at org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.execute(FetchPhase.java:182)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeFetchPhase(SearchService.java:501)
```

This is my master node statistics

```
{
"timestamp": 1435219276968,
"cluster_name": "cluster1",
"status": "green",
"indices": {
    "count": 537,
    "shards": {
        "total": 5314,
        "primaries": 2657,
        "replication": 1,
        "index": {
            "shards": {
                "min": 2,
                "max": 10,
                "avg": 9.895716945996275
            },
            "primaries": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 5,
                "avg": 4.947858472998138
            },
            "replication": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 1,
                "avg": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "docs": {
        "count": 60900916,
        "deleted": 50541
    },
    "store": {
        "size": "1tb",
        "size_in_bytes": 1192366468003,
        "throttle_time": "6.2m",
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 372988
    },
    "fielddata": {
        "memory_size": "0b",
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 11175
    },
    "filter_cache": {
        "memory_size": "1.6mb",
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 1705012,
        "evictions": 0
    },
    "id_cache": {
        "memory_size": "0b",
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
    },
    "completion": {
        "size": "0b",
        "size_in_bytes": 0
    },
    "segments": {
        "count": 36771,
        "memory": "3gb",
        "memory_in_bytes": 3236984326,
        "index_writer_memory": "0b",
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "index_writer_max_memory": "2.5gb",
        "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes": 2720768000,
        "version_map_memory": "0b",
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "fixed_bit_set": "0b",
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0
    },
    "percolate": {
        "total": 0,
        "get_time": "0s",
        "time_in_millis": 0,
        "current": 0,
        "memory_size_in_bytes": -1,
        "memory_size": "-1b",
        "queries": 0
    }
},
"nodes": {
    "count": {
        "total": 3,
        "master_only": 0,
        "data_only": 0,
        "master_data": 2,
        "client": 0
    },
    "versions": [
        "1.5.2"
    ],
    "os": {
        "available_processors": 24,
        "mem": {
            "total": "95.9gb",
            "total_in_bytes": 103077617664
        },
        "cpu": [
            {
                "vendor": "Intel",
                "model": "Xeon",
                "mhz": 2400,
                "total_cores": 8,
                "total_sockets": 2,
                "cores_per_socket": 4,
                "cache_size": "-1b",
                "cache_size_in_bytes": -1,
                "count": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    "process": {
        "cpu": {
            "percent": 17
        },
        "open_file_descriptors": {
            "min": 1361,
            "max": 57055,
            "avg": 38465
        }
    },
    "jvm": {
        "max_uptime": "2.9d",
        "max_uptime_in_millis": 251100991,
        "versions": [
            {
                "version": "1.8.0_45",
                "vm_name": "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
                "vm_version": "25.45-b02",
                "vm_vendor": "Oracle Corporation",
                "count": 3
            }
        ],
        "mem": {
            "heap_used": "18.2gb",
            "heap_used_in_bytes": 19577530528,
            "heap_max": "47.8gb",
            "heap_max_in_bytes": 51330416640
        },
        "threads": 325
    },
    "fs": {},
    "plugins": []
  }
  }
```

EDIT:

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "fields": [
    "docid"
  ],
  "explain": false,
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": [
        "content"
      ],
      "ids": [
        "AU2h82DxWiT16vBNxqGo"
      ],
      "min_term_freq": 1,
      "min_doc_freq": 1,
      "include": "true",
      "max_query_terms": 1000,
      "boost_terms": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how many documents live in those 600 indices and how many indices does your query cover, but 600 indices with 5 shards means 3000 shards for two nodes. If you have replicas, as well, this means at least 6000 shards on two nodes. That's a lot (to be read - too much). And I wouldn't be surprised, if your query spans many indices or has some crazy `size` specified to it, your nodes to run out of memory.

Comment: I have edited my question with adding master node statistics,If this can help out to figure out the problem

Comment: And what is the query that you are running?

Comment: Your documents are quite large - 19KB on average. Still, I'm curious to see your query.

Comment: here is my query          {
size:100,
fields:["docid"],
"explain": false,
 "query": {
    "more_like_this" : {
        fields :["content"],
        ids : ["AU2h82DxWiT16vBNxqGo"],
        min_term_freq: 1,
        min_doc_freq: 1,
        include:"true",
        max_query_terms:1000,        
        boost_terms:1
        
       
    }
    }
}

Comment: If you lower `size` to 20, for example, do you still run OOM? The same goes for for `max_query_terms` - lower it to 50 and test.

Comment: I even tried above settings for size and max_query_terms but memory keeps on increasing and does not come down even after the search is finished.If I will search for some more documents then sure shot it will result into OOM because I have faced this situation

Comment: Right, but you don't run in OOM after a single run. The query is too heavy and puts too much pressure on the memory. What ES version is this?

Comment: In situations like this one takes a heap dump and looks inside it to see what the heap contained when it ran oom.

Comment: ok thanks.can you please guide me some good utility to analyse the heap

Comment: Eclipse MAT or Yourkit.